# How do you define a queue overflow exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, queue, overflow

This is the method. Deﬁne a queue overﬂow exception and modify enqueue so that it throws this exception when the queue runs out of space.

this is my code:

```cpp
void IntQueue::enqueue(int num)
{

    if (isFull())
        cout << "The queue is full.\n";
    else
    {
        // Calculate the new rear position
        rear = (rear + 1) % queueSize;
        // Insert new item
        queueArray[rear] = num;
        // Update item count
        numItems++;
    }
}
```

how can i insert an exception message here?

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error("queue full");`?

Comment: `insert an exception message` and `define a queue overflow exception ..` do not mean the same thing

Comment: how about catching an overflow?? how do you do it

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the call to `cout <<` by a

```
throw std::runtime_error("queue full");
```

Comment: thank you for this. But how can you catch the overflow if they occur?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are required to define your own exception type then something like the following

```
#include <stdexcept>

struct QueueException : public std::runtime_error
{
    QueueException(const char* msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
};

void IntQueue::enqueue(int num)
{
    if (isFull())
        throw QueueException("queue full");
    else
        ...
}
```

If you don't want to define your own exception type then just throw a `std::runtime_error` as hivert showed.